# error of updating an C# web service application by accessing a URL from MS installer command "msiexec" in C# VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-installer, publish

This question is related to my previous question.

I need to publish a C# application (that has been set up in IIS 6.0 and built in VS2010) to a desktop with win7.

I have set up IIS on my desktop well. Now I can install the application on my laptop by accessing the URL

```
  http://myDesktopName.domain.com/MyApp
```

pointing to a physical location in desktop

```
  e:\myPath\myApp\myAppService.svc
```

When I publish a new version of the web service, the application should get updated when I open it.

But, it gave me an error:

```
**the filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**
```

After searching online, I found this error is normally caused by some unacccepted chars in the link. Here is the code that the msi (MS installer) needs to access and get the new version of the application.

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msiexec", "/favmuso \"" + myurl + "\"");
```

here,

```
myurl is http://myDesktopName.domain.com/MyApp/MyAppSetup.msi
```

Here, http://myDesktopName/MyApp/ is the virtual directory set in IIS 6.0 on my desktop. I can access and download it from IE in my laptop without any problems.

But, when the application notified me that a new version is available for updating the old one, I clicked the pop-up ballon on the application icon and then I got the error:

```
 Error 123. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

If I try to access it from the C# code, I got the same error.

Then, I did a test by running

```
 msiexec **/favmuso** http://myDesktopName.domain.com/MyApp/MyAppSetup.msi /Lv mapp_msi.log
```

In the log file, i found :

```
 MSI (s) (80:DC) [18:04:33:089]: SECREPAIR: Failed to open the
```

file:http://myDesktopName.domain.com/mypath/\myAppSdetup (10).msi for computing its hash. Error:123

```
 Error 123. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Why my applcation setup file name was changed to

```
\myAppSdetup (10).msi
```

The  "/favmuso" options can be found at

```
 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_Install
```

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: We've also run into this with our installer that we create using wix. Our users mostly install directly from our server using `msiexec /i url` to enable LUA patching. Not so great that repair doesn't work though and we'd rather not whitelist ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed that you've asked this question elsewhere, and everyone was focused on the /favmuso piece of it.

I've been recently exeriencing this issue when trying to repair MSIs with a URL source when the original application was installed by SCCM 2012.

The workaround I found was to add a registry value at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer**. The value below causes the MSI to skip the problematic portion of the repair and move on.

**Name:** SecureRepairPolicy

**Type:** REG_DWORD

**Value:** 1

To be a bit safer, you look into setting the registry value to 2 and using a whitelist as described in this Microsoft article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2918614. (Ctrl+F "Steps to opt-out the affected programs".)